# SQL: aggregate functions with DATE type columns

Tags: sql, date, aggregate-functions, ansi-sql

I stumbled upon a question (in a test) about which aggregate functions are applicable to DATE type columns. So, as I understand it, COUNT will just count the number of rows, and MIN and MAX return the earliest/latest date. However, I'm a bit confused about SUM and AVG functions. Will they just convert the DATE values to ints and calculate sum/avg on those ints? Or am I wrong here? Anyway, is this behaviour consistent across all implementations of SQL?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "COUNT will just count the number of rows". Actually that's not quite correct. You're right that `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows, but `COUNT(somedatetypecolumn)` counts the number of rows where `somedatetypecolumn` is not NULL.

Comment: Oh, right, I wasn't explicit enough there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MS SQL Server You cannot call the `SUM` operator on `datetime` types, nor can you call the `AVG` operator.

MSDN lists the return types of the `SUM` operator here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

It is also a valid reference for the types on which you may *invoke* the `SUM` operator.

**EDIT:** In response to your comment, you may use a site like sqlfiddle to test various implementations

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22cee/1

Considering the backend storage of `datetime` is not standardized, I contend that it should **not** be depended upon for any database to return `SUM` or `AVG` results in predictable ways.... better not to do it at all...

Comment: That's interesting, because I tried SUM and AVG on a DATE type column in MySQL, and it returned just that - a sum and an average of ints. Thank you for your answer!